# str_extract_all getting stuck

Tags: html, r, timeout, txt

I am trying to read large text files and extract certain parts of the text.
First I clean the txt file, and then I use str_extract_all. It works perfecly as long as the cleaned text is not too big. As soon as I use "cleaned" instead of "cleaned_head" the code runs for a very long time and seems to get stuck (I dont think it actually does, but I can't figure out how far it is).

```
read_as_text = readLines(text_file, warn= F)
html_text = paste(read_as_text, collapse = " ")
html_cleaned = sub("<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC.*", "<DESCRIPTION>GRAPHIC", html_text)


cleanFun <- function(htmlString) {
  return(gsub("&.[^;]*;", "", gsub("<.*?>", "", htmlString)))
}
cleaned= cleanFun(html_cleaned)

#I use this as a test
cleaned_head <- substr(cleaned, 1, 50000)  # Adjust the end position as needed


pattern <- paste0( "(?i)(", start_pattern, "(.*?))(?!(?:", end_pattern, ")\\s*\\d+\\s*Performance)(.*?)(", end_pattern, ")")

matches <- str_extract_all(cleaned_head, pattern)
```

I would like:

1. A way to build in an error/break that as soon as more than 1 minute has elappsed, the code stops searching and goes to the next text file. withTimeout doesn't do the job.
2. More insight in the function str_extract_all. I have been looking everywhere and also into the source code. But I would like to see more detailed info on the function while running. E.g. which lines are already read, which line(s) cause so much trouble.
3. Ideally, a way of circumventing this issue.

Hope anyone can help me out.

For example I tried:

```
extractletter <- function(text,pattern){
  matches <- str_extract_all(cleaned_head, pattern)
  return(matches)
}`

res <- NULL
tryCatch({
  res <- withTimeout({
    extractletter(cleaned_head, pattern)
  }, timeout = 0.01)
}, TimeoutException = function(ex) {
  message("Timeout. Skipping.")
})
```

But still the code keeps running for a very long time.

Comment: Welcome to SO, Tira! It's difficult to troubleshoot problems or benchmark code without sample data. Can you please [edit] your question and place a representative _sample_ (not huge, please) of one of your text files into a code block? (This is mostly under the premise that we can solve whatever problem is causing the code to hang. If you really have no interest in this, then `withTimeout` is certainly the right direction.)